# Adding percentage in grouped barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I would like to as how can I include the percentage difference in the grouped bar plot
This is the data frame that I have

[image]

The code that I have:

```
library(scales)
library (ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
pivot_longer(-fuel_type) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=fuel_typ, y=value,fill=name))+
geom_col(position=position_dodge()) + 
scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","blue")) +
scale_y_continous(labels=label_comma()) + 
theme_bw()
```

(above code is credited to @Tarjae)

the output:

[image]

May I know how can I label the percentage difference of "no_car_21" relative to "no_car_18" on top of the "no_car_21" bar chart, with positive or negative signs?

Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, Adam! Please do not post an image of code/data/errors [for these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). If you want to post your data type `dput(df)` into the console and copy the output starting with `structure(....` into your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could calculate the percentage change per group with previous value using `lag` and assign them to `geom_text` with adjusting the `hjust` and `vjust` like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(fuel_type = c("DIESEL", "DIESEL/ELECTRIC", "LPG", "PETROL", "PETROL/ELECTRIC"),
                 no_car_18 = c(47817, 14, 904, 333872, 3653),
                 no_car_21 = c(3992, 199, 2224, 215199, 30550))

library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-fuel_type) %>%
  group_by(fuel_type) %>%
  mutate(pct = (value/lag(value)-1)*100) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=fuel_type, y=value,fill=name))+
  geom_col(position=position_dodge()) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","blue")) +
  geom_text(aes(y = value, label = round(pct, 2)), hjust = 0, vjust = -0.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=label_comma()) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Could you please explain the `-1` in `mutate(pct=...`?

Comment: Hi @TarJae, It is to calculate the percentage difference. It is actually the same as `(value-lag(value))/lag(value)` which was maybe better to write;)